# How to convert DD/MM/YYYY "13/09/21" to just "Tuesday, April 1"

Tags: android, kotlin, time

Good afternoon I want to convert my simpledateformat to show "Tuesday, 1st April" for example from "15/09/21", I was wondering how do I convert it to this? I have attached an image of what it looks like before.

My code calling the date:

```
            addAll(pending.sortedByDescending { it.finishDate.convertToDate()?.time })
            addAll(accepted.sortedByDescending { it.finishDate.convertToDate()?.time })
```

Where the time gets called:

```
fun String.convertToDate(): Date? {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    return try {
        sdf.parse(this)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        Timber.e("wrong date format - parsing not possible")
        null
    }
}
```

[Date Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7JhP.png)

Comment: "15/19/21" does not look like a valid date

Comment: if you're talking about the image its 15/09/21?

Comment: date mentioned in your question is wrong , in image it's correct

Comment: my fault, its been fixed now

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Is `finishDate` a `String`? Don’t keep your date in a `String`. Keep it in a `LocalDate` (`LocalDate` is class from java.time).

Comment: Does your code work the way it should?

Comment: finishdate is a api call from a website @OleV.V.

Comment: Yeah the code all works per usual, Im just wondering could I convert the date format as I wanted?

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated and troublesome, as suggested by @Ole V update to `DateTimeFormatter` , Here's a sample code for same

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = null;
        String date  = "2021-09-16T11:36:15";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMM d"); // use MMMM to show full month name
            Log.e("Date", "" + dateTime.format(formatter2) );
        }
```

To use this below android 8 , use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

**Output** Thursday, Sep 16

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fun changedate(olddate:String):String{
        var changedDate:String = ""
        try {
            val dateFormatprev = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
            val d: Date = dateFormatprev.parse(olddate)
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd")
             changedDate = dateFormat.format(d)
            println(changedDate)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return changedDate
    }
```

usage

```
 Log.e("TAG",changedate("01/01/2021"))
```